Expect script fails when outputting command as getting stuck on "--MORE--"
I have a simple expect script running on Ubuntu which I want to automate via cron. The script works fine if I manually run it with my terminal window full screen however if it is smaller than that of the output that's being generated, or via a cron job, then it stops as normally would need interaction each time it hits "--MORE--".
All the script does is SSH to a remote piece of network hardware, run several commands and that output is being read into a txt file.
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60

spawn ssh user@<remote IP>

expect "yes/no" { 
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" { send "password\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "password\r" }

expect "OLT01>" { send "comamnd 1\r" }
expect "OLT01>" { send "command 2\r" }
expect "OLT01>" { send "command 3\r" }

expect "OLT01>" { send "exit\r" }

The output where it stops.
  Uptime                : 8 days, 22:06:47
--MORE--master@ubuntu:~/$

I have tried looking online for others with this issue however unless I'm not wording it correctly it seems like it's just me experiencing this.
Any ideas very much welcome.

If you disable TTY emulation, that may well be the easy solution here (no TTY == there's no such thing as a screen size at all, and more intelligent systems will disable pager support in that scenario -- no knowing if your network hardware is "more intelligent" in that context, but it's worth testing). That should be the -T argument to ssh.

Of course, you can also tell your expect command to match (and provide behavior for) more than one string, and you can make one of those strings be ---MORE---; but better to sidestep the problem altogether.

...speaking of which, have you looked up whether the hardware in question has a command you can send to disable paging explicitly? (You haven't told us what it is, so we can't look that up ourselves; but for anything from a longstanding/established manufacturer I'd expect that to be available; search for "pager" or "paging" in the docs as the keyword most likely to be a hit).

Thanks. I have tried -T option however it now hangs after the password prompt (both via expect and ssh direct). Hardware in question is a Calix E7 GPON OLT, which has no reference to PAGER anywhere from what I can see in any doco.

Have you tried command 1 | cat\r etc.?

disable session pager -- see page 284 of https://paultclark.com/network/calix/Calix%20E-Series%20(E7%20OS%20R2.5)%20Command-Line%20Interface%20(CLI)%20Reference.pdf

Add a newline before \r, thus expect "OLT01>" { send "comamnd 1\n\r" }

This is fantastic ... I've been trying to deal with --more-- for years, all kinds of acrobatics in my expect script. SSH -T works wonders. Thanks
